# Prove the inequality $(x^4+y^4+z^4)+(x^5+y^5+z^5)+(x-y)^6+(y-z)^6+(z-x)^6 \le6$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z \in [0;1]$. Prove the inequality
$$(x^4+y^4+z^4)+(x^5+y^5+z^5)+(x-y)^6+(y-z)^6+(z-x)^6 \le6$$

#### My work so far:

Let $f(x)=(x^4+y^4+z^4)+(x^5+y^5+z^5)+(x-y)^6+(y-z)^6+(z-x)^6 -6$, where $x\in[0;1]$

$f(0)=(y^4+z^4)+(y^5+z^5)+(y)^6+(y-z)^6+(z)^6 -6$

Comment: I'm not convinced that your approach is the best one.  I would approach it by first considering each term in the sum.  For instance, on the given intervals, the maximum that the term $x^4 + y^4 + z^4$ can take on is 3, and this also is the same maximum for the second term at the same point $(1,1,1)$.  However, that means that the other terms must be zero.  Think about a similar argument for maximizing the other terms.  Where are they maximized?  What happens to the remaining terms?

Comment: I have just simplified the inequality by performing \begin{align*}
& (x^4+y^4+z^4)+(x^5+y^5+z^5)+(x-y)^6+(y-z)^6+(z-x)^6 \leq \\&
\leq 2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2 = \\ &
= 4(x^2 +y^2 +z^2) -2(xy +yz+xz).
\end{align*} But I don't know how to proceed from this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alex Silva starts off with the reduction

$$\begin{align*} & (x^4+y^4+z^4)+(x^5+y^5+z^5)+(x-y)^6+(y-z)^6+(z-x)^6 \leq \\& \leq 2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\end{align*}$$

Now note that

$$(x - y)^2 \leq (1 - x)^2 + (1 - y)^2$$

which is true because it is equivalent to

$$-2xy \leq -2x + 1 - 2y + 1 \implies x + y \leq 1 + xy \implies y(1 - x) \leq 1 - x$$

The last inequality is certainly true because $(1 - x) \geq 0$ and $ y \in [0,1]$. From here, note that

$$(1 - x)^2 \leq 1 - x^2 \qquad x \in [0,1]$$

So we get

$$(x - y)^2 \leq 2 - x^2 - y^2$$

We can repeat this argument for the other terms to get

$$(x - y)^2 + (x - z)^2 + (y - z)^2 \leq 6 - 2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$$
$$\implies 2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + (x - y)^2 + (x - z)^2 + (y - x)^2 \leq 6$$

Again, credits to Alex Silva for giving the reduction. Let me know if there are any algebra mistakes.

EDIT:
In general, we have for $x,y \in [0,1]$ the following fact

$$|x - y|^k \leq (1 - x)^k + (1 - y)^k \leq (1 - x^k) + (1 - y^k)$$

where the first inequality follows from the fact that given $x$ and $y$, the distance between them is always less than the distance between $x$ and $1$ and/or the distance between $y$ and $1$. The second inequality follows from the fact that

$$(1 - x^k) = (1 - x)(1 + x + \dots + x^{k-1}) \geq (1 - x)$$
$$\implies (1 - x^k) \geq (1 - x) \geq (1 - x)^k$$

so really the proof is unnecessary because of this general case.